# Table of biggest prime factor of every integer in 2 ... 10^K

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, computational-mathematics

How would you precalculate a big table of the **biggest prime factor of every integer** in $2 \dots 10^K$? The goal would be to do it once for all, save it to a file, and reload it later for fast computations (involving [smooth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number)). I tried with R:

```
library(gmp)    # the fastest factorization I've found on R, faster than number theory package "numbers"
v = sapply(2:10^7, function(x) as.integer(max(factorize(x))))
save(v, file="bpf.dat")
```

allowing later to load it with: `load("bpf.dat")`.

But this is very slow (35 seconds for $K=6$, 390 seconds for $K=7$ , etc.). 
**Which number-theoretic idea could be used to generate such a table faster?**

---

Note: I've already looked at https://oeis.org/A006530.
Note2: This question has been removed in mathoverflow (because too obvious), but I wanted to post here question+answer thanks to the helpful comments that were provided.

Comment: The algorithm to generate $\text{Lpf}(n) = \sup_{p | n} p$ for $n  \in 1 \ldots N$ is the Eratosthenes sieve which is $\mathcal{O}(C \sum_{p \le N} \lfloor N / p \rfloor) = \mathcal{O}(N \log \log N \ C)$ in time and $\mathcal{O}(N C)$ in memory, where $C \approx \log_2 N$ is the size of your representation of $n$ in memory. Clearly you can't do much better.

Comment: If you *need* a table of primes for something, an internet search turned up a result already created for $K=12$.

Comment: [Link to data dump](http://www.walter-fendt.de/m14e/primes.htm) - I just searched "table of primes"; I assume you can do the same?

Comment: @Basj Do you understand the asymptotic complexity I provided ? The main point is $\sum_{p \le N} \frac{1}{p} \sim \log \log N$ (Mertens theorem). But as a first estimate, you may say $\sum_{p \le N} \frac{1}{p}\le \sum_{n \le N} \frac{1}{n} \sim \log N$.

Comment: The prime number theorem yields with partial summation $\sum_{p \le N} f(p) \sim \sum_{n \le N} \frac{f(n)}{\log n}$ for any $f(n) = n^a , a \ge -1$.

Comment: Yes indeed @reuns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment of a now-deleted question, a modification of the **sieve of Eratosthenes** will produce this information very quickly, almost in linear time. Here is some C code to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

const int MAX = 1000000000;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> largest(MAX);

    for (int i = 2; i < MAX; ++i)
        largest[i] = i;

    for (int i = 2; i < MAX; ++i)
        if (largest[i] == i)
            for (int j = i+i; j < MAX; j += i)
                largest[j] = i;

    for (int i = 2; i < MAX; ++i)
        std::cout << largest[i] << std::endl;
}
```